# How do i handle it when i can't find a variable

Tags: excel, vba, find

I've written some code with the intention that on the worksheet "main" it will cycle through the rows,taking the value from the cell in column C (Reg) and then moving to the relevant tab depending on the beginning letter of the corresponding cell in column B. however sometimes (Reg) doesn't exist on any other tab and I can't work out how to handle it when it can't find (reg) in any of the other corresponding tabs.

I've tried to use on error goto next but that just ends up causing issues further into the Loop when it's pulling back values from cells that I didn't intend for it to look at. My VB is basic really so I'm not sure of how I could be dealing with this better as there is a lot of .select in my code and I've been told I shouldn't use that.

```
Sub comments_chase()

Dim comment, chase As String
Dim Reg As String
Dim reg_add As String
Dim Foundrange As String



Application.ScreenUpdating = False



    Workbooks("Progression chases.xlsm").Activate

    Worksheets("main").Activate



    Range("C4").Select



    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

    reg_add = ActiveCell.Address

    Reg = ActiveCell.Value

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select



    On Error GoTo Error_step



    If Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "L" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "M" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "N" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "O" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "P" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "Q" Then

    Worksheets("Adie").Activate

    Set Foundrange = Range("C:C").Find(Reg, LookAt:=xlWhole).Select

        If Foundrange Is Nothing Then

        GoTo Error_step

        Else

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Select

    comment = ActiveCell.Value

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

    chase = ActiveCell.Value

    Workbooks("Progression chases.xlsm").Activate

    Worksheets("main").Activate

    Range("C:C").Find(Reg, LookAt:=xlWhole).Select

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Select

    ActiveCell.Value = comment

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

    ActiveCell.Value = chase

    End If



    On Error GoTo Error_step



        ElseIf Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "A" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "B" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "C" Then

        Worksheets("Andy").Activate

    Set Foundrange = Range("C:C").Find(Reg, LookAt:=xlWhole).Select

    If Foundrange Is Nothing Then

    GoTo Error_step

    Else

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Select

        comment = ActiveCell.Value

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

        chase = ActiveCell.Value

        Workbooks("Progression chases.xlsm").Activate

        Worksheets("main").Activate

        Range("C:C").Find(Reg, LookAt:=xlWhole).Select

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Select

        ActiveCell.Value = comment

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

        ActiveCell.Value = chase

        End If



On Error GoTo Error_step

            ElseIf Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "D" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "E" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "F" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "G" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "H" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "J" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "K" Then

            Worksheets("Georgia").Activate

    Set Foundrange = Range("C:C").Find(Reg, LookAt:=xlWhole).Select

    If Foundrange Is Nothing Then

    GoTo Error_step

    Else

            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Select

            comment = ActiveCell.Value

            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

            chase = ActiveCell.Value

            Workbooks("Progression chases.xlsm").Activate

            Worksheets("main").Activate

            Range("C:C").Find(Reg, LookAt:=xlWhole).Select

            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Select

            ActiveCell.Value = comment

            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

            ActiveCell.Value = chase

            End If



On Error GoTo Error_step

                ElseIf Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "R" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "S" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "T" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "U" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "V" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "W" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "(" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "[" Or Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = "*" Then

                Worksheets("Leona").Activate

    Range("C:C").Find(Reg, LookAt:=xlWhole).Select

    Foundrange = ActiveCell.Value

    If Foundrange Is Nothing Then

    GoTo Error_step

    Else

                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Select

                comment = ActiveCell.Value

                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

                chase = ActiveCell.Value

                Workbooks("Progression chases.xlsm").Activate

                Worksheets("main").Activate

                Range("C:C").Find(Reg, LookAt:=xlWhole).Select

                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Select

                ActiveCell.Value = comment

                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

                ActiveCell.Value = chase



            End If

Error_step:  Worksheets("main").Activate



            Worksheets("main").Activate

           Range(reg_add).Select

           ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

           End If



    Loop



End Sub
```

The above code has 2 slightly different attempts to handle it. to show what I've tried

I'm getting runtime error 424 Object required and on debug it's stopping at "If Foundrange is Nothing Then"in the block referencing sheet ("Leona")

Ideally if it all worked correctly i would have hoped that it found the (Reg) on sheet ("Leona") and brought back the values in Comment and Chase and then put them into the relevant cell on sheet (Main)

can anyone help with where I've gone wrong?

Comment: `Set foundRange = Worksheets("Leona").Range("C:C").Find(Reg, LookAt:=xlWhole)`.

Comment: But to improve your code, consider [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Also avoid relying on `Activate` and `ActiveCell`

Comment: I've just tried {Set foundRange = Worksheets("Leona").Range("C:C").Find(Reg, LookAt:=xlWhole).select} but i got a type mismatch error. Also thanks for that link about avoiding select, i'll go through that when i get time.

Comment: Don't `Select` and `Dim foundRange As Range`.

Comment: ah, i'll try that now

Comment: That's great. thanks loads for that